# Remember click before changing pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way to remember the click that transitions to a new page using jquery. I have a page where a tree drop down structure transitions to a new page. If the user comes back to previous page, i'd like to have the tree expanded as it was before. The page from which it happens uses a `.live('click')` function. I don't have any code that I did so can't paste anything here. Just looking out for suggestions or hints! :)

Comment: Read up on [cookies(link)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javasciprt+cookies&oq=javasciprt+cookies&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5674j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=91&q=javascript+cookies&safe=off&spell=1)

Comment: Use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie and works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).  When the tree is expanded, store it:

```
document.cookie = "tree=open";
```

When the user visits the page, check for it:

```
if (document.cookie.search(/tree-open/) != -1) {
    ...
}
```

My code is over-simplified to help you look in the right direction.  You may want to borrow a JS cookie library.

Comment: Use this developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie and works great.

Answer (score -1):

If your application is in HTML5 then you can use HTML5 Web Storage and save the clicked link in it and on load check if some link was clicked then open that else open the first link, you can check it in jquery easily.

thanks
abhishek